# Changing android phone orientation causes divs to disappear

Tags: android, html, css, android-layout

I have [a simple web page](http://yaddahost.co.uk/blvdmock2/) with a content section and a `position:fixed` menu on the left hand side.

When I view it on an `Android` phone and change the orientation to landscape the menu disappears. It reappears when you turn the phone back to portrait.

This problem only seems to appear on later versions of `Android` - it works fine on my older `(v2.2) Android` and the page works fine on `iOS`.

Edit: I'm not sure if the Android tags that someone added are really appropriate. This is a problem with the CSS of a web page when viewed in the Android web browser...

Answer (score 2):

have you tried setting the viewport?

Something like this as the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Actually it does help a bit. See my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to check the media queries in the css? this would be my first guess.

something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:320px) and (max-height:480px){
    .element_name{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no media queries in the css.

Comment: i checked the page on an android simulator with 4.1.2 and I see what you are talking about. what happens if you remove the images? just for testing

Comment: looks like you fixed it because right now it looks fine... what did you do?

Comment: Hmmm... I added the viewport meta tag as Marty suggested. You're right, it works until you zoom out enough to see the full image, then it reverts back to the same problem.